# Internet Explorer won't close my tab with $ie.Quit() because of Redirection

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer

If i would like to close the latest internet explorer tab that i opened with powershell - it doesn't work - because i get redirected to another site for login. Anyone have ideas how to fix this?

```
        try
    {
    
        Write-Host "Starting Internet Explorer to get login token..."
        $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application 
        $ie.visible = $true
        $ie.Navigate("redirectLink")
    
        Start-Sleep -s 3
    
        $ie.Quit()

...
```

Comment: I tried to test the issue but I am not able to produce the issue with the above code. Tab get closed properly. If the URL is public then you can try to share it. Other than that you can try to inform us which OS build you are using for making this test may help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the code you have listed on Windows 10, v2004, using a redirect link from a Google Ad. I've also tried just manually changing the page on the tab. In both instances, when the `$ie.Quit()` runs, it closes the tab that had been opened. I ran the code with the link below:

```
Write-Host "Starting Internet Explorer to get login token..."
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwijmJW6muDqAhVRPa0GHYV_B-IYABBcGgJwdg&sig=AOD64_2UgwCRNkwusFaFWEyYsktiUml6DA&ctype=46&rct=j&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjrppC6muDqAhXIi54KHVnCAREQwzwIUw&adurl=")
    
Start-Sleep -s 3
    
$ie.Quit()
```

I cannot reproduce the error, so my current theory is that this is not merely redirection (wherein, one page sends you to a different page within the same tab). I suspect that whatever link you are traveling to opens a new tab and closes your existing tab as part of its process (close window, open window). As such, I would recommend using the function provided by Andy Schneider in this answer to explicitly call the window that needs to be closed:

[How to close a tab in existing IE window using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575365/how-to-close-a-tab-in-existing-ie-window-using-powershell)

```
Function Close-IETab {
param($url)

    $oWindows = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows

    foreach ($oWindow in $oWindows.Invoke()) {

        if ($oWindow.Fullname -match "IEXPLORE.EXE" -and $oWindow.LocationURL -match $url) {

            Write-verbose "Closing tab $($oWindow.LocationURL)"
            $oWindow.Quit()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The rpc server is unavailable. (exception from hresult 0x80070 6ba) now occurs. Do you have any idea?     
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,start.ps1

Comment: When I initially ran my code, played around with it, then tried it again, I received that error. Run the `$ie.Quit()' section a couple of times to clear out the 'cache' in powershell and give it another go.

Comment: I don't know why, but my script is not working with ie.quit but if i try it just with the console it is working. Do you know this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I just tried running this code several ways in my environment, but the $ie.Quit() works in the iterations. Are you running this from a scheduled task, or right clicking and 'run with powershell'?

Comment: @plattio, Try to pause the code after IE.Quit. If there is any error then it will get displayed. Try to run the script using Windows Powershell ISE. It will also help to get the error information. Try to debug the code using Windows Powershell ISE.

Comment: Now the error message "the RPC server is unavailable" occurs. I have this error since 3 days. If i try it manually it works fine.

Comment: Is this exact code you are running on your side or your code is different? Check whether IE browser object get changed or get null before IE.quit() line.  In that situation, this kind of error may occur. It looks like there is some connection issue between the script and IE object.